# Undefined reference to _sbrk

Tags: c, gcc, arm, sbrk

I am having a problem with `_sbrk`. In a link phase of compilation i use below comand to link my objects and i get undefined reference to `_sbrk`.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -static -T linkerscript.ld -o exe timer_example.o /home/ziga/projects/cs_lite/arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a /home/ziga/projects/cs_lite/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.1/libgcc.a
```

I am compiling for **arm926ej-s** and in ARM mode so i think i have chosen the right multilib  *(`libc.a` and `libgcc.a`)* which is located in folder `home/ziga/projects/cs_lite/arm-none-eabi/lib/`.

I have been searching internet for `_sbrk` function and it is some sort of a memory managment call which isnt included in standard C libraries as it is dependant on microprocessor. So do I have to write `_sbrk` function on my own? How do I do it? Do you have any example for **arm926ej-s**? After writing this function I intend to compile it into an object file and link it together with other objects, libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem and will post solution here so i give something back to comunity. The function `_sbrk` is located inside NXP CDL package for ARM. Package is available for download *(link is for all who dont know this already)* [here](http://www.lpclinux.com/Downloads/WebHome) in subfolder `CDL_v005/csps/lpc313x/bsps/ea3131/source` you will find source file named `libnosys_gnu.c` which should be added to the project and compiled to object file and after that linked to executable file alongside other objects and libraries.

Best wishes and a lot of success.

Answer (score 23):

This helps:

> -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard

The important switches "seem" to be:

> -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same problem, and adding those to the linker flags helped:

```
-specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs
```

Also, just with the nosys.specs fixed the issue, but the code size was a lot bigger.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has little to do with `_sbrk` itself, but rather your attempt to invoke the linker directly, bypassing the compiler driver. Instead, use the gcc command to invoke the linker and the `-Wl,-linkeroptionhere` syntax to pass extra options to the linker.

One possible solution, if you must invoke the linker yourself.. Try repeating both `libc.a` and `libgcc.a` a second time at the end of the command line. There's also some "as group" linker option you could use to achieve this but I don't know it right off.

Answer (score 3):

recently I also ran into this(again). the easiest solution which worked for me was to provide/redirect "malloc" and "free" apis to the one available from the SDK on which I was building my application.

Basically it happens because of mem management apis missing while linking. like the above answer mentions its not that _sbrk is specifically missing here. brk/sbrk syscall intenrally is used for heap management. hence the _sbrk ,missing link when it comes to mem management apis.

I noticed that adding -lnosys (i.e libnosys.a) also helped a this to a degree in some integrations.

Answer (score 3):

with visualgdb (using gcc), and nanolib, I had to add the linker flag

```
-specs=nosys.specs
```