# Does the stm32f769 board support c standard library?

Tags: c++, stm32f7

I am currently trying to get familiar with stm32f769 board. I noticed that when I use malloc I get a build error.

```
undefined reference to `_sbrk'
```

I am not really familiar with micro-controller development, so am not sure if this error is because stdlib doesn't exist for or something else.

These are the compiler flags I am using:

```
ARCH_FLAGS=-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffast-math

CFLAGS=-ggdb -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Warray-bounds -Wno-unused-parameter $(ARCH_FLAGS) $(INC) -DSTM32F769xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER
```

Comment: compiler? compile flags?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764414/undefined-reference-to-sbrk

Comment: I have already seen that post and specs flags dont solve the issue. Am not sure if it matters but I am using cortex m7 rather than m4

Comment: which compiler do you use?